# pg_dump making gibberish characters even with UTF8 encoding

Tags: postgresql, docker, encoding, django-cms, pg-dump

I have a new project of django-cms which is multilingual (en, ar, nl) with a postgres database, i am trying to migrate it but when i use pg_dump i am getting gibberish characters for arabic and some of the dutch characters.
I am using the following command:
`docker exec <container-name> /bin/bash -c "PGPASSWORD=password pg_dump --username postgres db -E Unicode" > dump.sql`

example of the dump file:

```
COPY public.cms_title (id, language, title, page_title, menu_title, meta_description, slug, path, has_url_overwrite, redirect, creation_date, published, publisher_is_draft, publisher_state, page_id, publisher_public_id) FROM stdin;
2   en  Home                home        f   \N  2023-06-30 14:45:24.059952+00   t   f   0   2   1
1   en  Home                home        f   \N  2023-06-30 14:45:24.059952+00   t   t   0   1   2
6   en  About us                about-us    about-us    f   \N  2023-06-30 14:59:02.257638+00   t   f   0   6   5
5   en  About us                about-us    about-us    f   \N  2023-06-30 14:59:02.257638+00   t   t   0   5   6
4   en  Services        Services        services    services    f   \N  2023-06-30 14:58:39.413029+00   t   f   0   4   3
3   en  Services        Services        services    services    f   \N  2023-06-30 14:58:39.413029+00   t   t   0   3   4
12  nl  Services                services    services    f   \N  2023-07-07 15:43:31.759413+00   t   f   0   4   11
11  nl  Services                services    services    f   \N  2023-07-07 15:43:31.759413+00   t   t   0   3   12
9   nl  Home                home        f   \N  2023-06-30 16:41:19.141036+00   t   f   0   2   7
13  nl  Over ons                over-ons    over-ons    f   \N  2023-07-07 15:42:32.291863+00   t   f   0   6   10
10  nl  Over ons                over-ons    over-ons    f   \N  2023-07-07 15:42:32.291863+00   t   t   0   5   13
14  ar  ╪º┘ä╪╡┘ü╪¡╪⌐ ╪º┘ä╪▒╪ª┘è╪│┘è╪⌐╪¿             home        f   \N  2023-06-30 16:42:01.91394+00    t   f   0   2   8
8   ar  ╪º┘ä╪╡┘ü╪¡╪⌐ ╪º┘ä╪▒╪ª┘è╪│┘è╪⌐╪¿             home        f   \N  2023-06-30 16:42:01.91394+00    t   t   0   1   14
7   nl  Home ├⌐├⌐n              home        f   \N  2023-06-30 16:41:19.141036+00   t   t   1   1   9
\.
```

if i dump the same database with heidisql i am getting the right results.
The database encoding is utf8

I am using docker desktop on windows 11

I tried giving another encoding than utf8 but none worked.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*):  `"╪º┘ä╪╡┘ü╪¡╪⌐ ╪º┘ä╪▒╪ª┘è╪│┘è╪⌐╪¿".encode( 'cp437').decode( 'utf-8')` returns `'الصفحة الرئيسيةب'` and vice versa: `'الصفحة الرئيسيةب'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp437')` -> `'╪º┘ä╪╡┘ü╪¡╪⌐ ╪º┘ä╪▒╪ª┘è╪│┘è╪⌐╪¿'`…  Maybe you could set right encoding for `stdin` using `CHCP 65001` _before_ running `docker` or _before_ typing the dump file (`type dump.sql`)?

Comment: So what JosefZ is saying is to check that your terminal or other applications on windows can display utf8 before using them to verify a dump

Comment: Windows does something weird with redirections. What if you have pg_dump write directly to the file, using `-f` rather than `>`?

Comment: The dump looks fine - perhaps you only have to look at it in an editor that can handle UTF-8.